# PermissionError: [Errno 13] in python .webassets-cache

Tags: 14.04, permissions, python, flask

So I got a 500 error after trying out a flask_assets Bundle. I have it working on my local machine, made to use Pyscss. But once I deployed I checked the error.log and saw that I had a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.../app/static/.webassets-cache'`

This is the script:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_assets import Environment, Bundle


app = Flask(__name__)

assets = Environment(app)
assets.url = app.static_url_path
scss = Bundle('scss/main.scss', 'scss/bootflat.scss', 'scss/metro.scss', 'scss/responsive.scss', filters='pyscss', output='css/all.css')
assets.register('scss_all', scss)
```

And I used this on my html:

```
{% assets "scss_all" %}
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/all.css') }}">
{% endassets %}
```

I'm guessing the permission error is due to webassets trying to update the all.css file.

My question is: How can I get around this permission error?

Comment: The title says "Errno 13" but your post says "Errno 14". Which one is correct?

Comment: sorry it was 13, I will edit that.